# Modifying "hosts file" on "Windows 10 IoT"

Tags: windows-iot

My Raspberry Pi 2 has Windows 10 IoT on it but I need to change the "hosts" file.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows IoT required Powershell so the edit command wasn't working:

ended up doing this:

1)

Powershell into your Raspberry Pi machine as Admin

```
net start WinRM

Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value MINWINPC

remove-module psreadline -force

Enter-PsSession -ComputerName MINWINPC -Credential MINWINPC\Administrator
```

(default password: p@ssw0rd)

2) Backup hosts file

```
Copy-Item C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts.old
```

3) Add Lines to hosts file:

```
add-content C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts "192.168.X.X test.com"
```

4) View modified hosts file:

```
Get-content -path C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should try the `edit` command.

```
edit c:\path\to\hosts
```